# Коннект редьюсеров. Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

делаю учебный проект на react/redux. Написал два редьюсера:

```
const currentInputDataReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    ....
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};

const expensesIncomeListReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    ....
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Для стейта вида:

```
const defaultState = {
  calcState: {
    currentInputData: {
      currentDate: '',
      currentMoney: '',
    },
    expensesIncomeList: [],
  },
};
```

Теперь хочу их скомбенировать и экспортировать:

```
export default combineReducers({
  currentInputDataReducer,
  expensesIncomeListReducer,
});
```

Чтобы в index файле создать хранилище:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

В компоненте использую connect:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(FormPanel);
```

В итоге появляется ошибка:

```
The above error occurred in the <ConnectFunction> component:
in ConnectFunction (created by Calc)
in div (created by Calc)
in Calc (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (created by App)
in Switch (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in App
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter
in Provider
```

Почему такое может происходить? Это стало появляться после того, как я разделил один редьюсер на два, и применил функцию combineReducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При объединении редюсеров главное состояние становится объектом, содержащим состояния этих редюсеров в значениях.

При вызове

```
combineReducers({
  currentInputDataReducer,
  expensesIncomeListReducer,
});
```

состояние будет иметь следующий вид:

```
state = {
  currentInputDataReducer: {<дефолтное состояние редюсера currentInputDataReducer>},
  expensesIncomeListReducer: {<дефолтное состояние редюсера expensesIncomeListReducer>}
}
```

При разделении состояния на несколько редюсеров нужно это учесть во всех объектах которые используют это состояние.
В вашем случае, скорее всего, объект состояния больше недоступен по старом имени типа `state.someObject`, теперь он должен быть `state.currentInputDataReducer.someObject` или `state.expensesIncomeListReducer.someObject` в зависимости от того где именно он оказался после разделения.
Ваши `defaultState` нужно разделить на два - каждому редюсеру своё.

---

Имена состояний можно установить при комбинировани редюсеров:

```
combineReducers({
  current: currentInputDataReducer,
  expenses: expensesIncomeListReducer,
});
```

Comment: Вы правы, state действительно имеет такую структуру, как вы написали. Подскажите пожалуйста, а как сделать так, чтобы эти два поля(управляемые редьюсерами), входили в родительский calcState, то есть, чтобы структура state была следующей: 
state = { calcState : { поле1: ... , поле 2 : ....} };    ?

Comment: @EgorG с редюсерами комбинированными через `combineReducers ` так сделать не получится.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!